# winston logger rotate folders per month and files per day

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I've a folder structure like below

- logs

  - 2023-07

    - info-2023-07-20.log
    - info-2023-07-21.log

where the logs is in the root directory and using winston i'm adding logs to the log files, files are automatically changing using winston-daily-rotate-file package but i also want to change the directory when the month get's changed which is not working, i've to restart my server to get it working otherwise it is only appending to the older folder that was created previously.

following is my codebase how i've setup my logger. (logger.js)

```
const fs = require('fs')
const winston = require('winston')
const { format, transports } = winston
const { colorize, combine, timestamp, printf, splat, errors } = format
require('winston-daily-rotate-file')

if (!fs.existsSync('logs/')) {
  fs.mkdirSync('logs/')
}

const todayDate = new Date()
const currentMonth = ('0' + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
const logDir = `logs/${todayDate.getFullYear()}-${currentMonth}` // Directory path for logs.
// month + 1 is because first month starts with 0
if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(logDir)
}

const logFormat = combine(
  timestamp({ format: 'HH:mm:ss' }),
  splat(),
  errors({ stack: true }),
  printf(({ timestamp, level, message, stack }) => {
    return `${timestamp},${global.isBackgroundServer ? ` [BG]:` : ''}${
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? ` ${level}:` : ''
    } ${typeof message === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(message) : message}${stack ? `, Stack: ${stack}` : ''}`
  }),
)

const defaultLoggerOptions = {
  format: logFormat,
}

const infoTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
  ...defaultLoggerOptions,
  level: 'info',
  filename: logDir + '/Info-%DATE%.log',
})

const errorTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
  ...defaultLoggerOptions,
  level: 'error',
  filename: logDir + '/Error-%DATE%.log',
})

const warningTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
  ...defaultLoggerOptions,
  level: 'debug',
  filename: logDir + '/Warning-%DATE%.log',
})

const consoleTransport = new transports.Console({
  format: combine(colorize(), logFormat),
})

const errorLogger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [consoleTransport, errorTransport],
})

const successLogger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [consoleTransport, infoTransport],
})

const warningLogger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [consoleTransport, warningTransport],
})

const transportConsoleToWinston = () => {
  const getArgumentsStr = (arguments) => {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ')
  }

  const wrappedSuccessLogger = (...args) => successLogger.log.apply(successLogger, ['info', getArgumentsStr(args)])
  const wrappedWarningLogger = (...args) => warningLogger.log.apply(warningLogger, ['warn', getArgumentsStr(args)])
  const wrappedDebugLogger = (...args) => warningLogger.log.apply(warningLogger, ['debug', getArgumentsStr(args)])

  console.log = wrappedSuccessLogger
  console.info = wrappedSuccessLogger
  console.warn = wrappedWarningLogger
  console.debug = wrappedDebugLogger
  console.error = (...args) => errorLogger.error.call(errorLogger, ...args)
}

module.exports = { errorLogger, successLogger, warningLogger, transportConsoleToWinston }
```

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing you cannot change the `dirName` and `fileName` properties at runtime. So you need to create a new transport each month, while creating (rotating) a new file every day. This is how I would do it. It relies on the rotate event that happens automatically every day. If there is not yet a folder with the current year/month, this means we're changing month so just create a folder and update the transport (see comments):

```javascript
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const fs = require('fs');

// Initialize the transport with the proper folder for the current month.
var transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
    dirname:'logs/'+ getDirName(),
    filename: 'log-%DATE%',
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD', // rotates every day
});

function getDirName(){ // returns current YYYY-MM
    var curDate = new Date();
    var curMonth = ("0" + (curDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var curYYYYMM = curDate.getFullYear() + "-" + curMonth;
    return curYYYYMM;
}

transport.on('rotate', function (_, _) {
    // Each time there is a file rotation (= every day with this date pattern), if there is not yet
    // a folder with the current name = if the month changed, then create a new transport and
    // set its directory to the new month:
    if (!fs.existsSync('logs/' + getDirName() + '/')) {
        transport = new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
            dirname:'logs/'+ getDirName(),
            filename: 'log-%DATE%',
            datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        });
    }
});

var logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        transport
    ]
});

async function demo() {
    while(true) {
        logger.info('Hello World ' + new Date().getSeconds());
        console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    }
}

demo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple idea for this question that I think is worth trying, we can use setTimeout and set setInterval to create logger:

```
function createLoggers() {
  if (!fs.existsSync('logs/')) {
    fs.mkdirSync('logs/');
  }

  const todayDate = new Date();
  const currentMonth = ('0' + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  const logDir = `logs/${todayDate.getFullYear()}-${currentMonth}`; // Directory path for logs.

  if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
  }

  const infoTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
    ...defaultLoggerOptions,
    level: 'info',
    filename: `${logDir}/Info-%DATE%.log`,
  });

  const errorTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
    ...defaultLoggerOptions,
    level: 'error',
    filename: `${logDir}/Error-%DATE%.log`,
  });

// Recreate the logger with a new date at midnight every day. 
setInterval(() => {
  const now = new Date();
  const millisTillMidnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 1) - now;

  setTimeout(() => {
    createLoggers(); //your crate logger logic
  }, millisTillMidnight);
}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

Your code creates the name for the logs folder only once and never changes it later.

### Solution

Well, `winston-daily-rotate-file` doesn't provide the way to use some placeholder for the `dirname` option the way it does for `filename` option and you can only use full date placeholder `%DATE%` anyway. So we have to recreate loggers manually every month. Here is one of many ways to do it:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const winston = require('winston')
const { format, transports } = winston
const { colorize, combine, timestamp, printf, splat, errors } = format
require('winston-daily-rotate-file')

if (!fs.existsSync('logs/')) {
  fs.mkdirSync('logs/')
}

const logFormat = combine(
  timestamp({ format: 'HH:mm:ss' }),
  splat(),
  errors({ stack: true }),
  printf(({ timestamp, level, message, stack }) => {
    return `${timestamp},${global.isBackgroundServer ? ` [BG]:` : ''}${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? ` ${level}:` : ''
      } ${typeof message === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(message) : message}${stack ? `, Stack: ${stack}` : ''}`
  }),
)

const defaultLoggerOptions = {
  format: logFormat,
}

let errorLogger, successLogger, warningLogger

function createLoggers() {
  const now = new Date()
  const currentMonth = ('0' + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
  const logDir = `logs/${now.getFullYear()}-${currentMonth}` // Directory path for logs.
  // month + 1 is because first month starts with 0
  if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logDir)
  }

  // Lets calculate time left to the begining of the next month and schudule recreation of loggers
  const nextMonth = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 1)
  setTimeout(createLoggers, nextMonth.getTime() - now.getTime())

  const infoTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
    ...defaultLoggerOptions,
    level: 'info',
    filename: logDir + '/Info-%DATE%.log',
  })

  const errorTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
    ...defaultLoggerOptions,
    level: 'error',
    filename: logDir + '/Error-%DATE%.log',
  })

  const warningTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
    ...defaultLoggerOptions,
    level: 'debug',
    filename: logDir + '/Warning-%DATE%.log',
  })

  const consoleTransport = new transports.Console({
    format: combine(colorize(), logFormat),
  })

  errorLogger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [consoleTransport, errorTransport],
  })

  successLogger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [consoleTransport, infoTransport],
  })

  warningLogger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [consoleTransport, warningTransport],
  })
}

const transportConsoleToWinston = () => {
  const getArgumentsStr = (arguments) => {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ')
  }

  const wrappedSuccessLogger = (...args) => successLogger.log.apply(successLogger, ['info', getArgumentsStr(args)])
  const wrappedWarningLogger = (...args) => warningLogger.log.apply(warningLogger, ['warn', getArgumentsStr(args)])
  const wrappedDebugLogger = (...args) => warningLogger.log.apply(warningLogger, ['debug', getArgumentsStr(args)])

  console.log = wrappedSuccessLogger
  console.info = wrappedSuccessLogger
  console.warn = wrappedWarningLogger
  console.debug = wrappedDebugLogger
  console.error = (...args) => errorLogger.error.call(errorLogger, ...args)
}

module.exports = { errorLogger, successLogger, warningLogger, transportConsoleToWinston }
```

##### Explanation

The big part of the code was wrapped into the `createLoggers` function. Precisely, the part, responsible for creation of changed pieces of logging functionality.
And there is a small block added inside:

```js
  // Lets calculate time left to the begining of the next month and schudule recreation of loggers
  const nextMonth = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 1)
  setTimeout(createLoggers, nextMonth.getTime() - now.getTime())
```

This block is responsible for calculating the beginning of the next month and scheduling the call of the `createLoggers` again.

#### Possible problems

- I have no chance to check this code thoroughly, but probably it could be improved to more precisely detect the beginning of the month
- I'm not sure if this way of recreating of the loggers could lead to memory leaks, but it shouldn't

Comment: you wrote code and didn't check it thoroughly? Or did you not write this code yourself?

Comment: @starball, I wrote it myself. Just because I haven't checked it thoroughly doesn't mean it can't be useful.  And I mentioned it honestly. So it's up to question's author to decide, will he/she use it as is or improve it. The idea stays anyway.